# Blazor - How to create a reusable Dialog component?

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, syncfusion, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to open a Dialog using the click event of a button inside a different blazor component, to do that I created an AppState class with a boolean variable.
At the onclick event the variable is updated, so the AppState class works correctly but the Dialog does not open.
Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

This is my Dialog component

```
@inject AppState appState;

<div class="popup-container">
    <SfDialog Target=".popup-container" Width="680px" Height="480px" IsModal="true" ShowCloseIcon="true" @bind-Visible="@appState.PopupCampaignVisibility">
        <DialogTemplates>
            <Content> 
                <div class="popup-content">
                    <div class="svg-container">
                       ///
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-container">
                        //
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <SfButton>Inizia da zero!</SfButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Content>
        </DialogTemplates>
    </SfDialog>
</div>
```

This is in my AppState class

```
 public bool PopupCampaignVisibility { get; set; } = false;
```

This is in my MainLayout Component

```
<PopupCampagna Name="Mauro"></PopupCampagna>
```

That's the component where i would like to open the Dialog

```
@inject AppState appState;

<div class="container-fluid p-0 navbarinf">
    <div class="row h-100 m-0">
        <div class="col-12 h-100 main-container">
            <div class="text-container">
                //
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <button @onclick="@(() => ShowPopupCampaign(true))">//</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string UrlSite { get; set; }

    void ShowPopupCampaign(bool b)
    {
        appState.PopupCampaignVisibility = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved by creating a reusable dialog as a service. Please follow the below steps to configure the reusable dialog,

Create folder Components in the root folder.
Add DialogOptions.cs class file and add below codes (If require more SfDialog properties, add and configure in DialogComponent).
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Blazor_Dialog_Service.Components

{

```
public class DialogOptions 

{ 

    public string Header { get; set; } 

    public RenderFragment Content { get; set; } 

    public RenderFragment FooterTemplate { get; set; } 

    public bool IsModal { get; set; } 

    public bool ShowCloseIcon { get; set; } 

}
```

}

Add DialogService.cs class file and add below codes
using System;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Blazor_Dialog_Service.Components

{

```
public class DialogService 

{ 

    public event Action<DialogOptions> DialogInstance; 

    public void Open(DialogOptions options) 

    { 

        // Invoke DialogComponent to update and show the dialog with options 

        this.DialogInstance.Invoke(options); 

    } 

}
```

}

Add DialogComponent.razor file and add below codes
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups;

@if (RenderDialog)

{

```
<SfDialog @ref="dialogObj" IsModal="@Options.IsModal" Width="250px" ShowCloseIcon="@Options.ShowCloseIcon" @bind-Visible="@Visibility">

    <DialogTemplates>

        <Header>@Options.Header</Header>

        <Content> @Options.Content </Content>

    </DialogTemplates>

    <DialogPositionData X="@Xvalue" Y="@Yvalue"></DialogPositionData>

</SfDialog>
```

}

@code {

```
[Inject]

public DialogService DialogService { get; set; }

SfDialog dialogObj;

private bool RenderDialog { get; set; } = false;

private bool Visibility { get; set; } = false;

private string Xvalue = "center";

private string Yvalue = "top";



// Parameter

private DialogOptions Options = new DialogOptions();

protected override void OnInitialized()

{

    // Update the parameter in local variable and render the dialog

    DialogService.DialogInstance += (DialogOptions options) =>

    {

        InvokeAsync(() =>

        {

            this.Options.Header = options.Header;

            this.Options.Content = options.Content;

            this.Options.IsModal = options.IsModal;

            this.Options.ShowCloseIcon = options.ShowCloseIcon;

            this.Options.FooterTemplate = options.FooterTemplate;

            this.RenderDialog = true;

            this.Visibility = true;

            this.StateHasChanged();

        });

    };

}

public async Task alertDialog()

{

    await this.dialogObj.HideAsync();

}
```

}

Register the DialogService in the StartUp.cs file as below
using Blazor_Dialog_Service.Components;

namespace Blazor_Dialog_Service

{

```
public class Startup 

{ 

    . . . 

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 

    { 

        services.AddRazorPages(); 

        services.AddServerSideBlazor(); 

        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>(); 

        services.AddSingleton<DialogService>(); 

        services.AddSyncfusionBlazor(); 

    } 

    . . . 

 }
```

}

Initialize the DialogComponent, end of the MainLayout.razor file for update the instance in DialogService
@using Blazor_Dialog_Service.Components

. . .

. . .

The inject DialogService and using the dialog component by calling the ‘DialogService.Open’ with the parameters anywhere in the code.
@using Blazor_Dialog_Service.Components

@inject DialogService DialogServices

<button class="e-btn" @onclick="@showDialog"> Show Dialog

@code {

```
private void showDialog()

{

    this.DialogServices.Open(new DialogOptions()

    {

  Header = "ALERT",

        Content =@<b>Test</b>, // Fragment loaded from external component

    });

}
```

}

We have also prepared a sample for your reference,

Documentation: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/common/extend-and-customize-components

Comment: I tried this and worked great. The only problem is that by loading DialogService as Singleton it opens the popup on other tabs, potentially other computers as well. Do you know how to achieve the same but loading as Transient instead?

Answer (score 0):

That would be a bad design. Components are capable to do what you need, through Functions and Events. Instead of changing a value in the appState object, you just call a Function of the Dialog component, that you define as public. In that Function, you can set the styles you need to show your dialog.
Your idea should work too, maybe you need to invoke StateHasChanged(); at the end of your ShowPopupCampaign Function.